# Changing position of div using its Id in javascript

Tags: html, css

This is my html code :

```
 <div id="d1" class="division">
    <input type="button" value="one" class="division">
    </div>

    <div id="d2" class="division">
    <input type="button" value="two" class="division">
    </div>
```

This is my css code

```
.division
        {
         top:50px;
         left:100px;
         display: none;
        }
```

But my div element part is not at all changing its top and left position.If its not the right method then How to change the location of a element using its class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define is position like so:

```
position: relative;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
```

Depending on how exactly you want to position the elements. Also using .division will position both elements.

Use the following if you want to just position one:

```
#d1 { ... }
```

Comment: And of course, you would need to remove "display: none" for it to actually show, as mentioned above :)

Comment: :Thanks. How to change the font size inside division class

Comment: `.division { font-size: 14px; }`

Answer (score 2):

`display: none` will make the element invisible.

Try this instead:

```
.division
{
  top:50px;
  left:100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming `display:none` is an initial setting modified by jQuery, for example. Otherwise, you won't see the element at all.)

You need to explicitly use `position:relative` (or similar, depending on the rest of your CSS) for the browser to render the position offsets.